# On click display Div, within that Div display Div1 for 3 sec then hide

Tags: javascript, show-hide, display

I am trying to display (when clicked) Div1 for 3 sec then hide and display Div2.

Sequence is...

When clicked >> div "slidingDiv" appears >> withing that Div1 appears for 3 secs >> Div1 hides (and does not appear on clicking again) >> Div2 appears.

I am not able to hide after 3 sec.

below is my code...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="show_hide" onclick="begin()">Show/hide</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">

<div id="Div2" style="display:none">
php code here</div>

<div id="Div1" style="display:none"><img id="myImage" src="ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function begin() {
function show1() {
document.getElementById("Div1").style.display="block";
setTimeout("hide1()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
}

function hide1() {
document.getElementById("Div1").style.display="none";
show2();
}

show1();
function show2() {
document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="block";
}
}
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: setTimeout(hide1, 3000); I think... check how to write it... not put it as a string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong part:

```
setTimeout("hide1()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
```

It has to be:

```
setTimeout(hide1, 3000);  // 3 seconds
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/yso7ajyb/